# Scroll menu not working on one page layout

Tags: css, layout

I've been troubleshooting this for a while now with no luck so I'm asking here in case someone is inclined to have a look.  Thank you in advance.

On this website:

http://www.oldsaltmerchants.com/

I have a one page layout with a menu that scrolls the page to the correct location.  Once the page scrolls past the top section a nav-menu drops down from the top edge of the window.  The yellow bar is supposed to span the full width of the page but it is hidden in the margin areas and only displays in the "content" area.

I could really use another set of eyes if anyone is interested.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Try removing width:910px from #menu.pinned ul

Answer (score 0):

may not be the correct answer but may give some clue. I changed width to 100% and add `text-align: center`

[image: css]

Comment: Thanks.  I see now this was a tweak I made to keep the menu items in the same fixed horizontal position.  Any suggestions on how to set that so that the #menu.pinned ul doesn't follow the right edge of the window as it expands?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `#menu.pinned ul` CSS selector's `width: 910px` attribute.
Remove it and it should display just fine.

[image]